# Today Widget not Showing Contents When PushNotificationIOS activated (React Native)

Tags: ios, objective-c, react-native, uilocalnotification

I've been having trouble understanding why my today widget isn't working after integrating the react-native-push-notification into my application. Has anyone experienced this problem? For example, I'm trying to display something as simple as: `<Text>Hello World</Text>` in my today widget. I followed the procedures to implement the widget in this article. https://medium.com/@jamesrochabrun/local-notifications-are-a-great-way-to-send-notifications-to-the-user-without-the-necessity-of-an-b3187e7176a3
I used `zo0r/react-native-push-notification` to implement local notification functionality.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure the `linked frameworks and libraries` are the same for both the widget and the project in which it resides. Once I made them the same, the widget contained the react-native view.